# DNF Counting Problem

Tags: algorithms, random

I am studying the DNF counting problem from the book Randomized Algorithm by Rajeev Motwani.

Then, by [Theorem 11.1(Estimator Theorem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Dv8.png), in order to have an $\epsilon$-approximation to $\mid G\mid$ with high probability, the sampling size 
$\begin{equation}N \geq \displaystyle\frac{4}{\epsilon^{2}\rho}\ln\frac{2}{\delta}\end{equation}$, where $\rho = \displaystyle\frac{\mid G\mid}{\mid U\mid}$.

My question is, our goal is to estimate the size of $\mid G\mid$, we need to repeat the sampling process more than $N$ times, so the value of $\rho$ should be probably known. But in that case, we know $\mid G \mid$, exactly.
That is what I am confused.

**UPDATE**

1. Here is a lecture note from CMU, [DNF counting](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f04/www/scribes/lec8.pdf). And above, $G$ denotes the set of satisfying assignments, while denoting by $S$ in CMU note.

Comment: What is the meaning of DNF ?

Comment: @Jean Marie, I have added a reference for DNF counting problem. Thank you.